# Unresolved reference: Coin in kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin, dice

hi I'm new in android programming and i try to flip a coin for practice more roll.dice in kotlin
so i wrote the code Bellow :

```
fun main(){
 val myFirstDice=Dice(6)
 println("Your ${myFirstDice.numSides} sided dice rolled ${myFirstDice.roll()}!")

 val mySecondDice=Dice(20)
 println("Your ${mySecondDice.numSides} sided dice rolled ${mySecondDice.roll()}!")
 
 val myCoin=Coin(2)
 println("Your ${myCoin.numSides} coin fliped ${myCoin.roll()}")
}

class Dice(val numSides :Int){
 
 fun roll() : Int{
      return (1..numSides).random()
     
 }
class Coin(val numSides :Int) {
 fun roll() :Int{
     return (1..numSides).random()
 }
}
 
}
```

but i have this problem :
*Unresolved reference: Coin
*

ty for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `}` on your `Dice` class. You need to be careful about copying everything - make sure every opening `{` has a closing one in the right place (Android Studio draws a vertical line so you can see where the block closes)